# Is there a way to force the DOM to update in between repeated calls to prompt in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, prompt

I am attempting to get a program to go into a cycle between prompts and updates on a page. However, if I isolate this problem down, in this case to two append calls and two prompts, the behavior I observe is that the page is updated visually only after the second call to prompt. The reason why I want to do this is esoteric, but related to making a program that sort of "feels" like a terminal where a user is typing in input once in a while. Here's an example, adapted from w3c schools, that demonstrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The Window Object</h1>
<h2>The prompt() Method</h2>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   
  let person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Prompt1");
  if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Test1\n");
 }
  
  person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Prompt2")
  if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Test2\n");
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I would "like" to happen is that in the first insertAdjacentHTML call that it updates the DOM, and visually on the page, before the second prompt, so you can see what you typed in. In practice, I observe that "Test1" and "Test2" visually appear at the same time after the second prompt. Console logging, as opposed to the insert adjacent call, works how I want, but isn't relevant to the application I'm writing.

I have experimented with various techniques to force the issue (e.g., trying to force trigger a layout with a scroll call, playing with requestAnimationFrame), but have not yet found a technique that seems to do what I want. My hypothesis, and I am not sure it is correct, is that the second prompt is called before the next frame, which means it blocks any new rendering, but that's just a hypothesis. Even if correct, suggestions on how to get the behavior I want would be appreciated.

Generally, I was hoping to observe Test1 placed on the page, then the second prompt call is fired, then after Test2, assuming the user chose the defaults.

Comment: Do not use any of `prompt()`, `alert()`, or `confirm()` in a new website. Prefer a non blocking UI like `<dialog>` and handle events instead.

Comment: I would also rather not use prompt/alert/etc, but unfortunately in this case it's a hard requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a short timeout seems to work...

```js
function myFunction() {
  const d = document.getElementById("demo");
   
  let person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Prompt1");
  if (person != null) {
    d.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Test1\n");
  }
 
  setTimeout(() => {
    person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Prompt2")
    if (person != null) {
      d.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Test2\n");
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

```html
<h4>Example with setTimeout</h4>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

BUT it will get ugly fast if you need a lot of prompts.  If so, maybe something that wraps the prompt/write text/delay part in a promise and chain them together with `then`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const d = document.getElementById("demo");
   
  delayPrompt("Please enter your name", "Prompt1", d)
    .then(() => delayPrompt("Please enter your name", "Prompt2", d))
    .then(() => delayPrompt("something else", "Prompt3", d));
}

async function delayPrompt(text, def, container) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {     
    let response = prompt(text, def);
    if (response != null) {
      container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', response);
    }
    setTimeout(resolve, 50);
  });
}
```

```html
<h4>Example with Promise</h4>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This helps, thank you. I'll hack around with this sort of idea and see if I can't coerce it to do what I need. One weird thing I've noticed so far is that while it runs correctly in the snippet, if I just copy paste the code into a raw HTML file, it actually never displays "Test2." I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. That's only true for the timeout solution. The promise one works as specified in both places. I'll hack on it.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer. Unfortunately after a tremendous amount of digging, I know this solution won't work for the use case I'm really doing. However, it does solve the problem as stated in my original question. Even though it didn't ultimately solve the actual problem, as opposed to my boiled down version, I appreciate it.